# How to declare the __init__ variables that is not necessarily required

Tags: python, class, init

```
class Gathering(object):

    def __init__(self, date, spent1, spent2, spent3, spent4):
        """Return a gathering object whose date is declared """
        self.date = date
        self.spent1 = spent1
        self.spent2 = spent2
        self.spent3 = spent3
        self.spent4 = spent4
        self.spent_total = spent1+spent2+spent3+spent4

    def per_person(self):
        return self.spent_total/3
```

I had made short script that I can easily calculate the portion of one person when me and my friend had some gatehring. We usally move the spots and spent different amount of money, but how many places we visit that night is always different.

So I"d like to make spent1,2,3,4 variables not necessarily required, how can I do that?

Comment: `def __init__(self, date, spend1=0, spend2=0, spend3=0, spend4=0)`

Comment: @Gang that's the spirit thx

Comment: @Gang to make it more robust, is there any way that those spend_n parts elongated auotmatically? like till spend1000 is also possilbe.

Comment: `d = {} ` , add sth to dict, `Gathering(**d)`

Comment: what does ** double asterisk refer to? I know one asterisk but not two of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a variable number of arguments:

```
class Gathering(object):
    def __init__(self, date, *args):
        """Return a gathering object whose date is declared """
        self.date = date
        self.spent = args
        self.spent_total = sum(args, 0)

    def per_person(self):
        return self.spent_total / 3.0
```

`sent` contains a tuple of values. You can use your class like:

```
g1 = Gathering(date1, 1, 2, 3)
g2 = Gathering(date2, 2, 3)
```

and so on.

Comment: thxs to you, now me and my friends can go as many as bars we want. thx